Is there a specific way to fetch async data when using React and Mobx?
I'm trying to learn Mobx with React.
I have problem to display fetched data.
I created store, context, provider and view component.
const API_URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";

class PostsStore {
    posts: Post[] = [];
    error: unknown = undefined;
    constructor() {
        makeObservable(this, {
            posts: observable,
            error: observable,
            addPost: action,
            fetchData: action,
        });
    }

    addPost(newPost: Post) {
        this.posts = [...this.posts, newPost];
    }

    fetchData() {
        fetch(API_URL)
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => (this.posts = data));
    }
}

export const postsStore = new PostsStore();

export const PostsProvider = ({ children }: React.PropsWithChildren) => {
    return (
        <PostsContext.Provider
            value={{
                error: postsStore.error,
                fetchData: postsStore.fetchData,
                posts: postsStore.posts,
            }}
        >
            {children}
        </PostsContext.Provider>
    );
};


export const usePostsContext = () => {
    const context = React.useContext(PostsContext);

    if (!context)
        throw new Error("usePostsContext must be wrapped between PostsProvider");

    return context;
};

const List = observer(() => {
    const context = usePostsContext();
    React.useEffect(() => {
        context.fetchData();
    }, [context]);

    return (
        <ul>
            {context.posts.map((post) => (
                <li key={post.id}>{post.title}</li>
            ))}
        </ul>
    );
});

export const Mobx = () => {
    return (
        <div className="h-full">
            <List />
        </div>
    );
};

I can see on the networks tab, that data is fetched, but component didn't re-render to display it. Why is that? Component is wrapped by observer. What i'm doing wrong?

You should make the context provide the entire store not just a single property, can show sample if you need more help

@ChibuezeOpata thank you. That solved my problem. But could you explain what's the difference?

Technically you're trying to watch an observable result without the modifiers, it's just generally safer to include the entire store or if you must the functions that modify the variables.
